# NextJS issue with Tailwind CSS default sizes and breakpoints

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have an issue in Next.js with using Tailwind and responsive breakpoints.

```html
<div className="w-96 md:w-full">...</div>
```

This div element always has full width for md or greater, and what I would assume that it is md or smaller. But even if I specify next higher breakpoint size, ex:

```html
<div className="lg:w-96 md:w-full">...</div>
```

the div is still always full width.

If I remove `md:w-full` the div is then `w-96`.

Any ideas?

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
const { Container } = require("postcss");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "pages/*.tsx",
    "pages/**/*.tsx",
    "src/ui/**/*.tsx",
    "src/ui/**/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
    },
    extend: {
      height: {
        sm: "50px",
      },
      colors: {
        white: "#fff",
        yellow: "#D5FF64",
        lightgray: "#596184",
        green: "#13ce66",
        "gray-dark": "#141620",
        gray: "#8492a6",
        "gray-light": "#d3dce6",
        "gray-text": "#6E7191",
        yellowrgba: "rgba(213, 255, 100, 0.2);",
        bglight: " rgba(89, 97, 132, 0.2);",
        darckgry: "#EFF0F7",
        secect: "#292E42",
        analogous: "#B7006E",
        rgbaanalogous: "rgba(183, 0, 110, 0.3)",
        popupbg: "rgb(41 46 66 / 45%)",
        switchs: "#596184",
        Crusta: "#F89358",
        newdarck: "#D9DBE9",
        colorcod: "#FCFCFC",
      },

      fontSize: {
        sml: "13",
        sm: "14px",
        md: "32px",
      },
      minHeight: {
        sm: "50px",
        calc: "calc(100vh - 150px)",
      },
      maxWidth: {
        "2xl": "1530px",
        calc2: "calc(100% - 440px)",
        lg: "calc(100% - 120px)",
      },
      tablewidth: {
        tbw: "16%",
      },
      screens: {
        xs: "100px",
        "2xls": "1535px",
      },
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans1: ["Archivo", "sans-serif"],
      mono1: ["IBM Plex Mono", "monospace"],
    },
  },
  darkMode: false,
  plugins: [require("tw-elements/dist/plugin")],
  breakpoints: {
    xs: "320px",
    sm: "576px",
    md: "768px",
    lg: "992px",
    xl: "1200px",
    "2xl": "1536px",
  },
};
```

I've tried to use a default sizes and then overide them on smaller screens with the `[breakpoint]:` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
className="w-full lg:w-96"
```

you need to understand that the **md** determines the medium and bigger not the smaller
so you start with smaller sizes and then specify the larger ones.

and it always takes full width even when you use ***lg:w-96 md:w-full*** because the **md** overrides on **lg**.

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with

```
 theme: {
       screens: {
        xs: { max: "320px" },
        sm: { max: "576px" },
        md: { max: "768px" },
        lg: { max: "992px" },
        xl: { max: "1200px" },
        "2xl": { max: "1536px" },
      },
    }
```